# JQuery not allowing symbols in variable

Tags: jquery

I am reading data from my database and including it in an array:

```
$return_arr[] = array('sequence' => $result["sequence"], 'response' => ($result["response"]), 'requires_edit' => $result["requires_edit"]);
```

I then `json_encode` this array data

```
$data = json_encode($return_arr);
```

and use it here in my JQuery code:

```
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
```

I have run into a small problem with this, and that is in my data there are `£` symbols included which is causing the data not to work in the `data` variable in JQuery.

How can I enable JQuery to allow these symbols - I have had a look around but cannot find anything other than changing the symbol to `&pound;` which is not an option.

My full PHP Code creating the array:

```
$return_arr = array();
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from tickets_standardresponses;");
while($result = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    $return_arr[] = array('sequence' => $result["sequence"], 'response' => htmlentities($result["response"]), 'requires_edit' => $result["requires_edit"]);
}
$data = json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: Why changing the symbol to `&pound;` is not an option? You don't need to change it in your database, you can just use PHP's built-in function called `htmlentities` to convert it from `£` to `&pound;`.

Comment: i have just tried this and the data is back in the `data` variable now but its not reading it correctly. it should put the data into a textarea input using jquery but its not doing that and no errors are being returned

Comment: Please post your jQuery code that is suppose to do that.

Comment: see my update - i have included the full PHP code that retrieves the data but it puts the `$data` variable into the jquery `data` variable

Comment: any ideas on this one?

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Don't know what the encoding of your page and database are, but try this: `utf8_encode($result["response"])`, if it does not work, try the other way around: `utf8_decode($result["response"])`